# Cannot run nunit tests with Nant

Tags: nunit, nant

I'm trying to launch nunit ui tests with nant and get the error:

> Buildfile: file:///c:/UItests/nant.build Target framework:
>   Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 Target(s) specified: build
>
> build:
>
> [nunit2] 2012/06/20/13:29:52: Exception in set up method: The
>   CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to Apar
>   tmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer.    [nunit2]
>   2012/06/20/13:29:52: Exception in set up method: The CurrentThread
>   needs to have it's ApartmentState set to Apar tmentState.STA to be
>   able to automate Internet Explorer.    [nunit2] 2012/06/20/13:29:52:
>   Exception in set up method: The CurrentThread needs to have it's
>   ApartmentState set to Apar tmentState.STA to be able to automate
>   Internet Explorer.    [nunit2] 2012/06/20/13:29:52: Exception in set
>   up method: The CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to
>   Apar tmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer.
>   [nunit2] 2012/06/20/13:29:52: Exception in set up method: The
>   CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to Apar
>   tmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer.

I tried with App.config that comes with my project, like this:

```
<test assemblyname="UITests.dll" appconfig="UITests.dll.config" />
```

And also I created config file manually and put it to folder with test and nunit assemblies. But nothing helped. In config file I have:

```
 <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
```

Here is nant.build file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <project name="UITests" default="build">
 <property name="build.dir" value="" />
 <target name="build">
  <nunit2>
<formatter type="Plain" />
<test assemblyname="${build.dir}UITests.dll" appconfig="UITests.dll.config" />
  </nunit2>
</target>
</project>
```

What I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible and simple solution:

set this:

```
[assembly: RequiresSTA]
```

in AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Nant is able to run the tests but the TestSetup is doing something which is not configured properly. Probably try writing and running a simpler test like `Assert.That( 10+1, Is.Equals(11));` and running that.
If it works then i think the question should be posted with more details on what and how you are testing

Comment: So, I created a very simple example: [TestFixture]
public class WatiNTest 
{   

    [Test]
    public void MyTest()
    {
        var ie = new IE();
        ie.GoTo("http://google.com");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ie.Close();
    }

} In App.config I have  <NUnit>
    <TestRunner>
      <!-- Valid values are STA,MTA. Others ignored. -->
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA"/>
    </TestRunner>
  </NUnit> Test is nicely running from Visual Studion with Resharper but fails if I run it with Nant.

Comment: Nant can only run the test if I marked it with "[STAThread]" attribute. My question is: why nant does not see App.config?