# Debugging WatiN UI tests in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, watin

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2010 that includes a test project that uses [WatiN](http://watin.org/).  It also has a test project with unit tests.  Both use NUnit as the framework.  I use [Gallio](http://www.gallio.org/) to run/debug the tests.

I'm trying out Visual Studio 2012.  My project builds fine.  I can use the NUnit GUI to run both sets of tests.  The Test Explorer lists all tests (unit and UI).  I can run/debug the unit tests from within Visual Studio.

When I run the UI tests from within Visual Studio 2012 I get an error:

> The CurrentThread needs to have it's ApartmentState set to
>   ApartmentState.STA to be able to automate Internet Explorer.

The error occurs on the following line in my TestFixtureSetup function:

```
browser = new IE(...);
```

I've [Googled the error](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=The+CurrentThread+needs+to+have+it%27s+ApartmentState+set+to&oq=The+CurrentThread+needs+to+have+it%27s+ApartmentState+set+to&gs_l=hp.3...449.449.0.1434.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les;..0.0...1c.1j2.m9qCxFMBCIo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=dd4e74f5654acd20&biw=1680&bih=989) and seen plenty of suggestions about adding lines to the app.config.  The odd thing is that I already have those lines.

```
<sectionGroup name="NUnit">
  <section name="TestRunner" 
           type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
</sectionGroup>

...

<NUnit>
  <TestRunner>
    <!-- Valid values are STA or MTA (Others are ignored) -->
    <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
  </TestRunner>
</NUnit>
```

Has anyone gotten WatiN working with the Test Explorer in Visual Studio 2012?  Any suggestions for getting it to work?  Are there known compatibility issues?

I also tried installing Gallio with the RC and it broke some things that required a bit of effort to fix.  I would prefer to use the integrated Test Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117804/cannot-run-nunit-tests-with-nant).

I added the following to my AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```
[assembly: RequiresSTA]
```

Still outstanding is why doesn't the test runner see the STA settings in the app.config?